# when I run Arima/Sarima Model getting errors - ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types or Panda on numpy cast

Tags: python, arima, sarimax

I am building ARIMA/Sarima Model in percentages but getting following error
1-
`model = SARIMAX(np.asarray(train), order = (0, 1, 1), seasonal_order =(1, 1, 1, 12))`

`TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

2- If i don't covert pandas data frame to numpy array i get following error
`model = SARIMAX(train, order = (0, 1, 1), seasonal_order =(1, 1, 1, 12))`

`ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).`

though few days back same code was working which I am using in step 2

Comment: Please also show us the data you are using.

Comment: issue was with input data :) it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

issue was with the input data format, few rows had commas so it was reading it as string. Once i removed it is working fine.